# For dataframe segmentation and sorting operations-spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

There are such dataframe and it has only one column.Each row  is Like that:

```
A:6,B:5,C:2
A:8,C:7,D:5,E:2,F:1
A:12,F:7,G:6,W:1
B:13,H:4,I:2
....
```

eg:Now I create a dataframe just with four rows:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  (A:6,B:5,C:2),
  (A:8,C:7,D:5,E:2,F:1),
  (A:12,F:7,G:6,W:1),
  (B:13,H:4,I:2)
).toDF("key_value")
```

Each row has at least three elements, and then each element is comma-separated.Behind each letter is its corresponding value.And The elements of each line have been sorted in descending order of value.Now I want to extract the combination of the top three values for each line, merge them together, and add the same letter values together and make them show like:

```
A:###
B:###
C:###
.....
```

PS:each row only has one element.How could I code this function?Plz help me!

Comment: Your requirement suggest to go with rdd rather than dataframe. So don't bother converting into dataframe. just do the calculation in rdd.

Comment: how should I do with rdd?Thx!

Comment: can you update the question with how you are creating the dataframe?

Comment: OK. I have updated it.

Comment: so each row is a string like `"A:6,B:5,C:2"` right?

Comment: please check the answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Analysis of your requirement suggest that use of RDD should be efficient and easy than to go with dataframes

So instead of creating a dataframe, create a rdd as

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("A:6,B:5,C:2"),
  ("A:8,C:7,D:5,E:2,F:1"),
  ("A:12,F:7,G:6,W:1"),
  ("B:13,H:4,I:2")
))
```

And use the following method to get your desired output ( I have explained and formatted for easy understanding)

```
rdd.flatMap(row =>                          //flattening the highest three key value pairs
  {
    row.split(",").map(array =>             //splitted the string row to array of each elements
      {
        val arrayed = array.split(":")      //splitted each element for key and value pairs
        (arrayed(0), arrayed(1).toInt)      // tuple2(String, Int) is created
      })
      .sortWith(_._2 > _._2)                // sorted in descending order of integer values
      .take(3)                              // take the highest three key value pair
  }
  ).reduceByKey(_ + _)                      // adding all the values with same key
```

You should have following output

```
(G,6)
(B,18)
(A,26)
(I,2)
(H,4)
(C,9)
(F,7)
(D,5)
```

I hope the answer is helpful